# Check if a packaged WPF Application ran with startup or manually?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, startup

I have a WPF application that is packaged for being able to submit it in the Microsoft Store. I've used [StartupTask extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask) to run it with system startup.

*Package.appmanifest (in the Package project of the solution):*

```
<Extensions>
  <uap5:Extension Category="windows.startupTask" Executable="*PathToExecutable*" EntryPoint="Windows.FullTrustApplication">
    <uap5:StartupTask TaskId="MyAppStartupTaskId" Enabled="true" DisplayName="Title in TaskManager" />
  </uap5:Extension>
</Extensions>
```

The problem is that there is no `Argument` property to set when running with startup, something like this:

```
<uap5:StartupTask Argument="/autostart" ... />
```

Then I could do something like this in the `Application_Startup` event:

*App.xaml.cs (in the Application project of the solution):*

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if application is running by startup
    if (e.Args.Length > 0 && e.Args[0] == "/autostart")
    {
        LaunchMinimized = true;
    }
    // Lots of bla bla blas here...
}
```

The question is can I check if a program is launched with system startup in a WPF application with this `StartupTask` thing? Does system startup launcher attach any event or property to my app or its launch args to check for startup?

Comment: You could query the PPID (parent PID) and based on that tell which process opened your program.

Comment: @IneedHelp Nice trick, but I'm afraid that PPID is a clue that I can rely on. I've just checked parent process of my app in auto started mode with Process Hacker, it is "explorer.exe". Unfortunately even if I run it manually, "explorer" would be the parent, so there is no difference in auto started mode and manual mode I guess, at least using `StartupTask`.

Comment: What are you trying to do different based on how it starts?

Comment: @IneedHelp As it is stated in second code example in the question, I want to run app minimized if it is launched with startup.

Comment: Following the link to the StartupTask article, it shows an example in c#; if you could implement your StartupTask in code-behind, you could then switch a bool static field that can be used to decide whether it should start minimized or not. I absolutely despise XAML and I do WPF purely in c#, so i have no idea if you can do what I just suggested in XAML.

Comment: @IneedHelp `StartupTask` is a part of universal windows application model. It is not something that I can implement. Even if I do, windows looks for it's own defined extension, not mine. And sadly, `Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTask` is [not supported in code-behind of packaged apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#apis-supported-in-both-converted-apps-and-desktop-applications) yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid you can't specify a parameter for a startup task, but if you are targeting Windows 10 version 18.03 or later you can use the [AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.appinstance.getactivatedeventargs) method to get an `IActivatedEventArgs` and then check its `Kind` property to determine whether the application was activated from a startup task.

The other option would be to launch a different .EXE from the start up task.

> Those APIs are coming from `Windows.ApplicationModel.dll` and `Windows.dll` assemblies that you can't add them to your WPF app

Sure you can. Make sure you have installed [the latest SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) and add a reference to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\10.0.17134.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\6.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd`.

Then you can call the method like this in your WPF app:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.IActivatedEventArgs args = Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();
```

Comment: Thanks, but calling `GetActivatedEvent` is [not supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#apis-supported-in-both-converted-apps-and-desktop-applications) from a WPF app.

Comment: I think multiple exe files is the best solution yet, I'll go with it if there were not any better solution.

Comment: It should be `GetActivatedEventArgs` and yes, you should be able to call this method from a desktop bridge app. Did you try?

Comment: Yes. Those APIs are coming from `Windows.ApplicationModel.dll` and `Windows.dll` assemblies that you can't add them to your WPF app.

Comment: WPF doesn't have those methods by itself. You should add a reference to it, but there are not any supported reference for it.

Comment: Thanks! APIs are now available and project compile successfully, but calling that method returns a `System.Exception`: `The text associated with this error code could not be found.`

Comment: Just as a note, you cant use `Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();` in `App.xaml.cs`, because `Application.Windows` hides that namespace. I should use `global::Windows.ApplicationModel.AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();` instead.

Comment: My bad, that exception only occurs in WPF project, not in the packaged one. In the packaged project `GetActivatedEventArgs` returns `null`. Based on docs, `This method only returns arguments on its first call. Subsequent calls return null.` But it returns null even in my first call.

Comment: I tried this in a WinForms project and when running through the packaged project it works just fine and I can see the difference between "Launch" and "StartupTask". So maybe they fixed it now. Running WinForms on .NET Core 3.1.